# Delete file with python after downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this script which downloads an excel file from google drive, updates the external link then runs a desired macro. However, I would like it so that the file is deleted from the path after the macro has been run so that I don't need to update the script to change the file name every time.

I've included the script only from the run macro part.

```
def run_macro(workbook_name, com_instance):
    wb = com_instance.workbooks.open(workbook_name)
    com_instance.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    try:
       wb.UpdateLink(Name=wb.LinkSources())

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)

    finally:
       wb.Close(True)
       wb = None    
    return True

def main():
    dir_root  = ("C:\\users\\ciara\\desktop\\test4.xlsm")

    xl_app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl_app.Visible = False
    xl_app.DisplayAlerts = False

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_root):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.endswith(".xlsx") and fn[0] is not "~":
                run_macro(os.path.join(root, fn), xl_app)
    xl_app.Quit()
    xl = None


import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\\users\\ciara\\desktop\\test4.xlsm')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('BridgeHit')
            wb.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

if os.path.exists('C:\\users\\ciara\\desktop\\test4.xlsm'):
    os.remove('C:\\users\\ciara\\desktop\\test4.xlsm')
else:
    print('File does not exists')
```

The console displays does not display even 'File does not exists'.
If there is any other feedback on the code above I would appreciate it! I'm just starting to learn

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an indent to your if-else block.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the file removal if-else block to ExcelMacro class. Then only, before running (or after) a macro, it could remove the file if it exists.

Comment: I've included it within the ExcelMacro class but I'm having a separate issue now. As the macro displays a MsgBox the script runs until I hit okay on it. This then gives WinError 32 that the process cant access the file as its being used in another process.

I can give a little workaround of time.sleep(10) to give the user a chance to review the MsgBox content and hit okay, but not an ideal fix